# Azure portal. Mvc. Redirect to custom error page doesn't work for 403 error

Tags: owin, http-status-code-403, authorize-attribute, azureportal, role-base-authorization

I have configured owin `role-based` authorization in my `MVC` application.
Then, I need to add a custom handling of `403` http error

I know two approaches to do it:

1. `Web.config` settings:

   ```
   <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/NoAccess" />
   </customErrors>
   ```
2. Configuration inside of overridden `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method in `Authorize` attribute:

   ```
   if (filterContext.HttpContext.User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
   {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
      new RouteValueDictionary
      {
        {"action", "NoAccess"},
        {"controller", "Error"}
      });
      //I've tried two variants of below: with below line as well as without it 
      filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
   }
   ```

Both of these methods work well in my local machine when I try to get access to resources which is not allowed for my user and I see my custom page for `403` error, but when I deploy my application on `azure` portal, I see only white page with the following text : '*You do not have permission to view this directory or page.'*. As I may understand, I need to configure this behavior on azure portal as well as I  configured it in my code.

Could someone advise with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.
The problem is appeared in case if I set response code in controller method manually as shown below:

```
public ActionResult NoAccess()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 403;
    return View();
}
```

In case if I delete this status setup, redirection works fine.
The solution is to set to true the following flag : `TrySkipIisCustomErrors`

```
 public ActionResult NoAccess()
 {
     Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
     Response.StatusCode = 403;

     return View();
 }
```

Then everything works correctly as well.